# Dependecy property does not update because it was created in another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml

I have an issue using a dependency property.

I have one `ObservableCollection<myUsercontrols>` used in a dependency property.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ActualMessagesProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("ActualMessages",
                                   typeof(ObservableCollection<myControls>),
                                   typeof(myPage),
                                   new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<myControls>()));
```

and a property bound in the xaml code

```
public ObservableCollection<myControls> ActualMessages
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<myControls>)GetValue(myPage.ActualMessagesProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(myPage.ActualMessagesProperty, value);
        this.OnPropertyChanged("ActualMessages");
    }
}
private static object lockActualMessages = new object(); here
```

I add this to my constructor:

```
BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(ActualMessages, lockActualMessages);
```

I have this method that is called from a static class with a static property changed by a different thread:

```
void Global_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "ActiveMessage":                           
            lock (lockActualMessages){this.ActualMessages = Global.ActualMessages;}
            break;
    }                
}
```

The `Global.ActualMessages` is a static property that comes from a static class.

This is my static class:

```
internal class Global
{
    private static ObservableCollection<myControls> actualMessages = new ObservableCollection<myControls>();
    public static ObservableCollection<myControls> ActualMessages 
    {
        get 
        {
            return actualMessages; 
        }
        set { actualMessages = value; OnPropertyChanged("ActualMessages"); }
    }
}
```

This class is used in a different thread, so when it changes the value and fires the `PropertyChanged` event, the dependency property should update the `ListView` in xaml.
All this doesn't work and I get back an access error stating that it's not possible to use this because it was created by another thread.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you try using _Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()_ method?

Comment: Just some notes. First, you should not call `this.OnPropertyChanged("ActualMessages")` in the setter of the `ActualMessages` property. It is neither necessary (because dependency properties have built-in change notification), nor is it reliably called, as WPF may bypass the setter and directly call `SetValue(ActualMessagesProperty, ...)`. Second, you should not assign a collection object as default value of a collection-type dependency property in PropertyMetadata. As metadata it is static, the default collection object is potentially used by multiple instances of your myPage class.

Answer (score 0):

Just because the `ObservableCollection<T>` source collection may be accessed from another thread it doesn't mean that you can set the dependency property of the control from another thread.

A control may only be accessed from the thread on which it was originally created - that is the UI thread.

Instead of setting the dependency property of the control you could try to clear and re-populate the source collection, e.g.:

```
void Global_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "ActiveMessage":
            lock (lockActualMessages)
            {
                this.ActualMessages.Clear();
                if (Global.ActualMessages != null)
                {
                    foreach (var message in Global.ActualMessages)
                        this.ActualMessages.Add(message);
                }
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

Obviously you need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue if you need any further help.